# Some url not loading in webview buts loading in the browser

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am trying to load a newspaper URL using my webview. Here is my webview settings:

```
 binding.webView.settings
        .run {
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            builtInZoomControls = true
            displayZoomControls = false
            domStorageEnabled = true
            databaseEnabled = true
            loadWithOverviewMode = true
            useWideViewPort = true
        }
```

The url I am trying to load is : [http://feeds.inquisitr.com/~r/google/yDYq/~3/1glI3navSEE/](http://feeds.inquisitr.com/%7Er/google/yDYq/%7E3/1glI3navSEE/)

but its not loading, however when I paste this url in browser the url get changed by the browser and it load perfectly. What else I need to do in my webview so that it will act like a browser and change(decode) the url.

p.s: when I load this url in browser the url becomes "https://www.inquisitr.com/6337911/big-brother-22-week-11-veto-winner/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+google%2FyDYq+%28The+Inquisitr+-+News%29"

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the shortened URL in the above example. You need to get the final URL in order to load into the `webView`. You can get final URL by implementing the following method:

```
public static String getFinalURL(String url) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        con.connect();
        con.getInputStream();

        if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) {
            String redirectUrl = con.getHeaderField("Location");
            return getFinalURL(redirectUrl);
        }
        return url;
    }
```

NB: This method is recursive in-case there are multiple re-directions.