# URL not loading on webview but loading on Browser correctly

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load a web url on my webview, its a [payment URL](https://pay.expresspay.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) (page shows the card details entering screen). This URL is working on the browser, its loading on browser bit its not working on android webview. Its log the `onPageStarted()` and `onPageFinished()` but its lot showing any errors such as `onReceivedError()` , `onReceivedSslError()`

I tried this [Some url not loading in webview buts loading in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64415980/some-url-not-loading-in-webview-buts-loading-in-the-browser) But its also not working with me,

Here is my code,

```
private void loadPaymentURL(){
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        Log.e("WEBVIEW", "PaymentURL : "+paymentUrl);

        try {
            paymentUrl = getFinalURL(paymentUrl);
        }catch (Exception e){}
        Log.e("WEBVIEW", "FinalURL : "+paymentUrl);

        webView.loadUrl(paymentUrl);
    }
```

`getFinalURL()` method I got this from this link [Some url not loading in webview buts loading in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64415980/some-url-not-loading-in-webview-buts-loading-in-the-browser) But its also not working with me,

```
public static String getFinalURL(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    con.connect();
    con.getInputStream();

    if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) {
        String redirectUrl = con.getHeaderField("Location");
        return getFinalURL(redirectUrl);
    }
    return url;
}
```

Here is my `WebViewClient` for the `webview`,

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.e("WEBVIEW", "onPageStarted() : "+url);
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.e("WEBVIEW", "onPageFinished() : "+url);
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            Log.e("WEBVIEW", "onReceivedError1() : "+error);
            view.goForward();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Log.e("WEBVIEW", "onReceivedError2() URL: "+failingUrl+" , Description:"+description);
            view.goForward();
            progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            Log.e("WEBVIEW", "onReceivedSslError() : "+error.toString());
            //progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.goForward();
        }


    }
```

Comment: can you add url which is not loading in webview but working fine on browser

Comment: its something like  https://pay.expresspay.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

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried my best to figure out issue but unfortunately not able to get cause of url not loading .

but if it urgent for you , you can go with this github library as it is working fine ..

https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

code

```
private fun loadUrl() {
   val webView = findViewById<AdvancedWebView>(R.id.webview)
   webView.loadUrl("https://pay.expresspay.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")
}
```

[image]